# Does anyone know how this sort of scrolling behavior can be replicated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If you take a look at [this site](http://redantler.com), it seems they built the whole thing in React. When you scroll, it's somehow much smoother (and maybe a bit "heavier") than a regular scroll. Looking online, it seems there are myriad solutions for this sort of behavior but only when you are specifically going to a certain point in the page, rather than just scrolling with a mouse.

Looking at the code, it is doing a `transform: translate3d` on the y-axis.

Is it possible to replicate this using a less complex JS or jQuery solution if I am not building a site in React?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but as you know, we don't write up code for users and will need a working code snippet to be able to actually help

Answer (score 0):

you should first search around, learn and try options before asking for the code... as [LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson) mentioned.

Anyway, on way would be:

http://jsfiddle.net/gmelcul/cZuym/ (from [gdsmith](https://github.com/gdsmith) I believe)

```
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

    handle(delta);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
    var time = 1000;
    var distance = 150;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time );
}
```

Just play with the values in handle function.

It uses **onmousewheel** which is deprecated (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onmousewheel.asp). Should be using **onwheel** (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onwheel.asp)

Give it a try